# new Date is formatting differently on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, datetime, firefox

I am passing this `new Date` into both Firefox and Chrome console (same computer, and time zone) and I am getting mixed results. Chrome is pushing the time forward to my time zone and Firefox is using the passed in time! So confusing...

**Firefox**

```
new Date("2014-02-27T17:00:00Z") // Passing in Console

// Result: Date 2014-02-27T17:00:00.000Z
```

**Chrome / Safari**

```
new Date("2014-02-27T17:00:00Z") // Passing in Console
// Result: Thu Feb 27 2014 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

It is 1 hour in the difference off. Chrome says the time is `18:00:00` while FF says the time is `17:00:00` which is what I expected seen as I formatted to Zulu (UTC) time.

Any help on how to get a consistent date on what is passed in to all browsers?

Thanks

Comment: Chrome parsed to local time

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, Chrome gives you a local time (GMT+0100). That why the hour part is different.

You can try converting to UTC string.

```
new Date("2014-02-27T17:00:00Z").toUTCString()
// both Chrome and Firefox will give you "Thu, 27 Feb 2014 17:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: thanks but is it not possible to have a working date object with the right time? If I convert this back to a date object I am back to the same issue

Comment: @Redwall if you just want the exact hour, `new Date("2014-02-27T17:00:00Z").getUTCHours()` will do. There are a set of UTC getter methods relative to normal getters.

Comment: Thanks but I want a date object that says 17:00 in both :) Your answer is not exactly what I am trying to achive but helps me explore different options..thanks